# After tapping on app icon its taking time to open app ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3

I am developing one app using swift 3, with support from iOS 9. But when I tap on app icon sometimes it takes long time to open the app. It shows an app selection in the dark. I haven't done anything in app delegate. Please let me know why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your program through instruments.

*Open Xcode: Open Developer Tool -> Instruments -> Choose the "Time Profiler"*

[image]

- The **Time Profiler instrument** captures stack trace information at
  prescribed intervals. It can record information from a single process
  or from all processes running on the system.
- The **Timeline pane** displays CPU and application life cycle
  information.
- Click the **Record Settings** button for recording options.
- Click the **Display Settings** button for display settings.

Comment: Thanks I will try this one , will let you know what's the result ??